# google sheet IF AND for a range of rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-sheets-api

google sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14PppjEwic_4N61A44BHhGMHwGecLqVqeOucWfg5YJmE/edit?usp=sharing

I have four columns of data, in the fifth column I want to have the result as **"yes"** or **"no"**

My criteria is
Yes = if column1 has "received" and column2 has "open" and column3 has `">20"` and column4 has `"<5000"`

I have the following does work only for one row and doesn't work with Arrayformula

```
=IF(AND(A2="received",B2="open",C2>20,D2<5000),"yes","no")
```

any help would be great, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In E2 try this formula

```
=Arrayformula(if(len(A2:A), if((A2:A="received")*(B2:B="open")*(C2:C>20)*(D2:D<5000)=1, "Yes", "No"),))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Can you please explain what is the use of "len(A2:A)," in the formula?

Comment: @kuruvi It limits the output of the formula to the rows that have a value in column A (by checking the length). The numbers returned by length will be coerced into booleans. If length = 0 this will make the condition false, if length > 0 the condition will be true. Does that make sense?